# How do bitizens choose the level to which they want to go?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

About random bitizens getting on the elevator saying "i wanna go to floor3" how is that decision made?

Are there some factors involved or is it completely random?

**Edit:**: 
Can you send bitizens to places where they do not want to go?

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your new question, too.

Answer (score 1):

The process is completely random. There does not seem to be any sort of process by which the level or type of floors creates any demand. I believe this is a difference from Tiny Tower where there was a demand system.

Edit (to match yours):  The only floors that you can send a bitizen to against their will are the Imperial floors.

I am basing this upon extensive game play and research online about the game.